# How will these frames be delivered to respective destination nodes?

Tags: ip, mac-address, osi, topology

I have the following 3 devices on my network(a **bus topology**): A,B,C

Let

**MAC(i)** - denote the MAC address of the device *i*.
**IP(i)**  - denote the IP address of the device *i*.

The devices B and C happen to have the following configuration:
MAC(B) == MAC(C) [I know it's very rare, but lets say B spoofed C's MAC]
IP(B) != IP(C)

A(has different mac and ip address from B,C) sends out a frame with
 Destination MAC address = MAC(B) [which is == MAC(C)]
Destination IP address = IP(C)

Will C recieve the frame or will it be ambiguous?  A nice explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Smells like homework. What do you think will happen?

Comment: I think may be that the frame will be stripped off using MAC address at the data link layer, both at B and C. But the network layer at B would reject the frame, because it doesn't match the IP address. Not exactly homework, it was in my exam and I wish to know the solution : )

Comment: Exam questions are explicitly off topic here. Instead of thinking about what layers do, think about what individual hosts do.

Comment: @RonTrunk i discussed it with my peers and searched the internet for it, but Nowadays no one actually uses OSI, so I thought of asking it here.

Comment: Layers don't do anything. They're just a mental model. Ethernet and IP are real protocols that have specific responses. Concentrate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is connecting the devices.

If it is a hub then the frame will be delivered to both B and C.

If it is a switch then the frame will be delivered to whichever of B or C most recently sent a frame to the switch.

If the frame arrives at C it will be processed normally.

If the frame arrives at B then asuming B is configured an end node it will probably drop it. If B is configured as a router then it may try to route the packet. This may end up with a duplicate packet arriving at C.